# How to change the word to be inclined in vim?

Tags: bash, vim

Is it possible to write a word in *italic* format in Vim?

Comment: I think [this](http://superuser.com/questions/825927/vim-how-to-bold-italic-underline-and-hypertext-specific-words) can answer your question.

Comment: You asked two questions: (Subject:) You need to edit the syntax [highlighting file](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#mysyntaxfile-add). (Body:) It depends on the capabilities of your terminal. Not all terminals support italic glyphs.

Answer (score 3):

No, vim is designed to work with plain text files which don't have different
styles. If you like you   it, but that's   .

(Just copy-paste this answer to your vim and you have italic and bold)

Comment: Pasting into vim, I have only question marks for the bold and italic part.

Comment: I used Unicode math and italic characters for the bold and italic part. Not every font has those glyphs. So it's not really practical.

Comment: Ok. But what are you saying about man pages syntax, for example, they use italic, bold and underline text formatting. May be this is a bash feature? And we are talking about any of the bash unpopular shortcuts? Most of them are working within Vim.

Comment: That's not a feature of the shell, but the terminal. You're mixing things up here.

Comment: Nonetheless, is it any _terminal_ shortcuts for changing text formatting?